Is it possible to daisy chain monitors using DP and HDMI ports?
I have a laptop that connects to my first monitor via USB type C (this cable also charges the laptop).
I want to connect this monitor with another monitor that only has HDMI port.
Is this possible?
I used a DP-male to HDMI-female converter to connect the first monitor's DP port to the second monitor's HDMI port but it isn't working. It recognizes the second monitor but it says no signal found.
Any ideas if this can be done?
Or I need to buy a second monitor with DP port?

Most laptops either support Type-C DP or Type-C HDMI but  it both, DP-HDMI is very difficult to achieve especially if it’s through Type-C
